# ask for android location in one intent and get it on another

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

I know how to get the GPS location, there are a lot of tutorials out there.

With enough time I can get the GPS location, but time is of the essence. And I would like to ask the current location when the AP opens and leave it ready to use on another intent; that in the new intent just ask for one update but the location is already set.

Right now I am doing it very simple:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Location");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alertDialog.show();
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is to use a service to get the location. The service can be started on the 'oncreate' of the application object that you would need to extend.  The location details can also be stored as a member variable on the application object that way any activity or service would be able to get it.

But you can also passed the location information through the intent if you have received it at that point.